# DBSCAN clustering plotting through ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am trying to plot the dbscan clustering result through ggplot2. If I understand it correctly the current dbscan plots noise in black colour with base plot function. Some code first,

```
library(dbscan)
n <- 100
x <- cbind(
  x = runif(5, 0, 10) + rnorm(n, sd = 0.2),
  y = runif(5, 0, 10) + rnorm(n, sd = 0.2)
)
plot(x)
kNNdistplot(x, k = 5)
abline(h=.25, col = "red", lty=2)

res <- dbscan::dbscan(x, eps = .25, minPts = 4)

plot(res, x, main = "DBSCAN")
x <- data.frame(x)
ggplot(x, aes(x = x, y=y)) + geom_point(color = res$cluster+1,  pch = clusym[res$cluster+1]) 
+ theme_grey() +  ggtitle("(c)") + labs(x ="x", y = "y")
```

I want two things to do differently here, first trying to plot the clustering output through `ggplot()`. The difficulty is if I use `res$cluster` to plot points the `plot()` will ignore points with 0 labels (which are noise points), and `ggplots()` will though error as length of `res$cluster` will be smaller than actual data to plot and if I try to use `res$cluster+1` it will give 1 to noise points, which I don't want. And secondly if possible try to do something which `clusym[]` in package `fpc` does. It plots clusters with labels 1, 2, 3, ... and ignores 0 labels. Thats fine if my labels for noise points are still 0 and then giving any specific symbol say "*" to noise point with a specific colour lets say grey. I have seen a stack overflow post which tries to do similar thing for convex hull plotting but couldn't still figure out how to do this if I don't want to draw the hull and want a clustering number for each cluster.
A possibility which I thought was first plot the points without noise and then additional adding noise points with the desired colour and symbols to the original plot  . 
But since the `res$cluster` length is not equal to x it is thronging error.

```
ggplot(x, aes(x = x, y=y)) + geom_point(color = res$cluster+1,  pch = clusym[res$cluster+1]) 
+ theme_grey() +  ggtitle("(c)") + labs(x ="x", y = "y") + adding noise points

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (100): shape, colour
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first subset the third column from the output of DBSCAN, tack that onto your original data as a new column (i.e. as cluster), and assign that as a factor.

When you make the ggplot, you can assign color or shape to cluster. As for ignoring the noise points, I would do it as follows.

```
data <- dataframe with the cluster column (still in numeric form).
data2 <- dplyr::filter(data, cluster > 0)
data2$cluster <- as.factor(data2$cluster)
ggplot(data2, aes(x = x, y = y) +
    geom_point(aes(color = `cluster`))
```